# PowerShell .NET Clickable link

Tags: .net, forms, powershell

I'm trying to create a link that is clickable, so that the e-mail program opens when the link is clicked. I found some information on how to do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linklabel(v=vs.100).aspx), but it's tailored to C#.

So far I have a `Panel` and the actual `LinkLabel`. But I don't know how to make the event happen that the e-mail client opens up:

**Code:**

```
    # Panel X: About
    $PanelAbout = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    $PanelAbout.Location = $PanelLocation
    $PanelAbout.Size = $PanelSize
    $PanelAbout.TabIndex = 8
    $PanelAbout.BackColor = $PanelBackColor
    $PanelAbout.BorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
    $Form.Controls.Add($PanelAbout)

    $PanelAboutLinkLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
    $PanelAboutLinkLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,8)
    $PanelAboutLinkLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20)
    $PanelAboutLinkLabel.DisabledLinkColor = 'Blue'
    $PanelAboutLinkLabel.VisitedLinkColor = 'Red'
    $PanelAboutLinkLabel.LinkBehavior = 'HoverUnderline'
    $PanelAboutLinkLabel.LinkColor = 'Navy'
    $PanelAboutLinkLabel.Text = Bob@mail.com
    $PanelAbout.Controls.Add($PanelAboutLinkLabel)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke the `add_Click` event, and within the event invoke `[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start("mailto:Bob@mail.com")` which should do the trick, like this:

```
$PanelAboutLinkLabel.Text = "Bob@mail.com"
$PanelAboutLinkLabel.add_Click({[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start("mailto:Bob@mail.com")})
```

There is a nice example of this [here](http://power-shell.com/2014/powershell-gui-tools/create-a-link-label-using-winforms/)